# Perdurance of a mean over a threshold

Tags: sql

I hope I can make this understandable, sorry if my English isn't perfect.
I have a database composed of dated data (measured every 5 minutes since March 2017).
My boss wants me to work on C# and/or SQL but I'm still a beginner in those ( Always been working on R).
The goal is to notice moments where the mean (for an hour or more) is superior to a threshold and for how long.
I've tried doing this by first doing a moving average;

```
Select DATEPART(YEAR,[Date]),DATEPART(MONTH,[Date]),
    DATEPART(DAY,[Date]),DATEPART(HOUR,[Date]),
    DATEPART(MINUTE,[Date]) as "minute", AVG(Mesure)
OVER(Order by DATEPART(YEAR,[Date]) ROWS
between 11 PRECEDING  and CURRENT ROW) as "moving_average"
from My_data_base
where Code_Prm = 920
```

I do have to keep the "Where" clause because it's how I can select only the value I need to work on .
From here I don't know if I could find a way to add the "Perdurance" of the mean, for example by concatenating when multiples rows return an average superior to `X`.

Or if I should rely on C# with multiple if conditions to try and get what I want

Hope this is understandable, thanks

EDIT :
The data is is stored in 3 fields( I don't know if there is a way to show it a better way)

| Date | Code_prm | Mesure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-03-10 11:18:00 | 920 | X |
| 2017-03-10 11:18:00 | 901 | X |
| 2017-03-10 11:18:00 | 903 | X |
| 2017-03-10 11:23:00 | 920 | X |

The expected result would be the average for an hour, for example : From 11:18 too 12:18, only if the average is superior to `X`.( I think I kind of did it with the moving average)
The next step and what I'm looking for how I could know if the mean superior to `X` lasts more than an hour, and then how much is it lasting.
Hour is "any hour" I guess, so 12 rows as there is a value every 5 minutes and
I'm sure there are no missing values!

Comment: Sample data and the expected result would help. Looks like gaps-and-islands well known sql problem.

Comment: And . . . tag with the database you are using.  And define "hour":  Is it a calendar hour, or just any hour, or the hour strictly before a given row?  How are missing values handled?

Comment: edited, hope this is better asked this way, thanks